# To display dataTable border in Pie chart Highcharts

Tags: javascript, css, django, highcharts, jinja2

The tabulation shown is done using Highcharts.drawTable as in,

http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d36fmcj5/

Since the table is rendered inside the piechart div manually, I need a way to add a border to the tabledata if possible, something like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9CGG.png)

Kindly help me out to fix this issue.

```js
$(function() {

  Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: [
      '#1cc88a', '#008a59', '#6adfb6'
    ]
  });

  Highcharts.drawTable = function() {

    // user options
    var tableTop = 200,
      colWidth = 60,
      tableLeft = 50,
      rowHeight = 20,
      cellPadding = 2.5,
      valueDecimals = 1,
      valueSuffix = '';

    // internal variables
    var chart = this,
      series = chart.series,
      renderer = chart.renderer,
      cellLeft = tableLeft;

    // draw category labels
    $.each(series, function(serie_index, serie) {
      renderer.text(
          serie.name,
          cellLeft + cellPadding,
          tableTop + (serie_index + 1) * rowHeight - cellPadding
        )
        .css({
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        })
        .add();
    });



    $.each(series[0].data, function(i) {

      renderer.text(
          series[0].data[i].name,
          cellLeft + colWidth - cellPadding,
          tableTop + (i + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding
        )
        .attr({
          align: 'right'
        })
        .add();
    });
    $.each(series[0].data, function(i) {
      renderer.text(
          Highcharts.numberFormat(series[0].data[i].y, valueDecimals) + valueSuffix,
          150,
          tableTop + (i + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding
        )
        .attr({
          align: 'left'
        })
        .add();

    });



  }




  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      //plotBackgroundColor: null,
      //plotBorderWidth: null,
      //plotShadow: false,
      events: {
        load: Highcharts.drawTable
      },
      height: 400,
      width: 800,
      //marginBottom: 250
    },
    title: {
      text: undefined
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
     showInLegend: true,
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
          verticalAlign: 'top',
          enabled: true,
          color: '#000000',
          connectorWidth: 1,
          distance: -50,
          connectorColor: '#000000',
          format: '<br>{point.percentage:.1f} %<br>Count: {point.y}'
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Vulnerability Counts',
      data: [{
        y: 4,
        name: 'high',
      }, {
        y: 8,
        name: 'medium',
      }, {
        y: 2,
        name: 'low'
      }]
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that a better solution is to use the `export-data` module which has implemented functionality to creates data tables and set `exporting.showTable` to `true`. The table rendered by this module could be styled by CSS.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f1qh3g58/

```
exporting: {
    showTable: true,
    tableCaption: false
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.showTable

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, But the problem is that, I have a combo box on top of pie chart for which the data will be loaded dynamically, For the first time, the data table loads correctly, but when I change the combo box, the new data is not updated with the design, Instead the values are loaded and displayed in the background without any table borders. There it looks like it is overwritten on top of previous data without any alignment. Kindly help me fix that

Comment: For example : [high:4,medium:8,low:2 ] are the values present now, I need the table to update to [high:0,medium:0,low:1] on changing a certain combo box. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems that everything works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s7m0tvpy/

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your support, I have created a new issue and provided a detailed explanation regarding the same. It would be great if you can help me understand the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63002388/highcharts-a-new-datatable-is-rendered-each-time-when-called-in-ajax-response