# A new datatable is rendered each time when called in Ajax response [Highcharts]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I have an Ajax response in which I am rendering a highcharts piechart and a data table. I have a combo box which I change everytime yields me a AJAX response. The function structure would look something similar to this:

In HTML part:

```
<select id="ValueSelect" onchange="updateValues()" class="select_dropdown">
</select>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 344px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

In Javascript part of it, I have a method:

```
function updateValues(){
            var val1 = $("#select1").val();
            var val2 = $("#select2").val();
                        $.get('/updatevalues/'+val1+'/'+val2+'/', function(response){
                        $(function () {
                            Highcharts.setOptions({
                            colors: [
                              '#144736', '#4e967d', '#6adfb6'
                            ],
                            lang: {
                                    exportData: {
                                        categoryHeader: 'Resultant Data'
                                    }
                                }
                          });

                            $('#container').highcharts({
                                chart: {
                                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                                    plotShadow: false,
                                    events: {
                                        render: Highcharts.drawTable
                                    }, 
                                    height: 300,
                                    width: 525,
                                },
                                title: {
                                    text: undefined
                                  },
                                legend: {
                                      align: 'left',
                                      layout: 'vertical',
                                      verticalAlign: 'top',
                                      alignColumns: true,
                                      itemWidth: 100,
                                      borderWidth: 1,
                                      height : 100,
                                      symbolPadding: 10,
                                      symbolWidth: 20,
                                      itemMarginTop: 5,
                                      itemMarginBottom: 5,
                                      x: 40,
                                      y: 25
                                },
                                credits: {
                                  enabled: false
                                },
                                exporting: {
                                    showTable: true,
                                    tableCaption: false,
                                    enabled: false
                                },
                                tooltip: {
                                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                                },
                                plotOptions: {
                                    pie: {
                                        allowPointSelect: true,
                                        cursor: 'pointer',
                                        dataLabels: {
                                                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                                                    enabled: true,
                                                    color: '#000000',
                                                    connectorWidth: 1,
                                                    distance: -40,
                                                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                                                    format: '<br>{point.percentage:.1f} %<br>Count: {point.y}'
                                                  }
                                    }
                                },
                                series: [{
                                    type: 'pie',
                                    name: 'counts',
                                    data: [{  y: response.value[0],
                                          name: response.header[0],
                                        }, {
                                          y: response.value[1],
                                          name: response.header[1],
                                        }, {
                                            y: response.value[2],
                                          name: response.header[2]
                                    }],
                                   showInLegend: true,
                                }]
                            });
                    }
                }
        };
```

**Actual Problem:**

Since I am giving *showTable = true* , The data table is rendered along with the pie chart during onload. When I change the combo box, I receive another JSON response from Ajax and the same pie chart is re-rendered again, however the same data table does not. Instead it produces a copy of itself and another new data table is created.

**Expected Behavior:**

During each AJAX request, I would like to update or re-render the values of same data table, instead of producing a copy of it.

**P.S:**

Since it is loaded in AJAX response, I am not sure how to reproduce this issue in JS fiddle. Other than the AJAX part, it would look something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f1qh3g58/

Comment: Try to update your series instead the creating a new one when the new data came from the Ajax request - http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s7m0tvpy/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel : Is there any wrong with the update functionality. It was working a few days back?
Is it deprecated and if so, could you let me know the alternate method for that?

Comment: it seems that it is a regression after the last updates. I reported it on the Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14427