# Unable to update datatable in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

Continuation of what I thought was resolved a couple of months ago:
[A new datatable is rendered each time when called in Ajax response [Highcharts]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63002388/a-new-datatable-is-rendered-each-time-when-called-in-ajax-response-highcharts)

```js
$(function() {
   Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang: {
            exportData: {
                categoryHeader: 'Vulnerability'
            }
        }
  });

  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      //plotBackgroundColor: null,
      //plotBorderWidth: null,
      //plotShadow: false,
      evsents: {
        load: Highcharts.drawTable
      },
      height: 400,
      width: 800,
      //marginBottom: 250
    },
    title: {
      text: undefined
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
              showInLegend: true,
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
          verticalAlign: 'top',
          enabled: true,
          color: '#000000',
          connectorWidth: 1,
          distance: -50,
          connectorColor: '#000000',
          format: '<br>{point.percentage:.1f} %<br>Count: {point.y}'
        }
      }
    },
        exporting: {
            showTable: true,
            tableCaption: false
        },
    series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Counts',
      data: [{
        y: 4,
        name: 'high',
      }, {
        y: 8,
        name: 'medium',
      }, {
        y: 2,
        name: 'low'
      }]
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 20px;
}
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}
.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table td, .highcharts-data-table th, .highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table thead tr, .highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**Overview:**

I have a condition where I need to update highcharts datatable every time when the change event is triggered.

http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s7m0tvpy/

This was working perfectly before in which clicking the **update** button changes 4,8,2 to 0,0,1.
But quite recently, this is not working.
Is it something that update function has been modified?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It works perfectly from here. Or I'm not understanding the issue.

Comment: @Gabriel : Thank you for your response. Actually, If you see the jsfiddle, you will find a "update button". Clicking on that, triggers addEventListener in Javascript and updates the pie-chart to the values set. But if you notice the data table, the value remains the same and not updated (not the same values as like pie-chart) . Earlier, when the pie-chart updates with new values, the data table also updates. But it is just recently, that I am not sure why the datatable is not updated even though the pie chart updates with new values.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was due to
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14320

However, it still works in 8.1.2 version.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.1.2/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.1.2/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.1.2/modules/export-data.js"></script>
```